# Set page title as link text in markdown/mkdocs

Tags: markdown, mkdocs

Is there a way for the link text to be generated from the title of the link target within the same site?

Suppose I have a page named `target.md` with `# Some Title Here`. Can I generate a link, say using the syntax `[#something](target.md)` (or any other way for that matter), that would automatically update the text as "Some Title Here" with the hyperlink to `target.md`?